# Save intent in shared preference

Tags: java, android

I have an application from which i can launch other apps installed on my phone, with a long click i get the app picker, in result i receive an intent data, how can i save it so the user when closes an comes back to my app has the same shortcuts setup?

i save other things like this

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
  editor.putInt("Counter1", counter);
  editor.putBoolean("FirstRun", firstRun);
  editor.putString("Label2", label2S);

  editor.commit();
```

But i can't do the same with the intent

Answer (score 8):

Ok i found a way
I save the intent like this

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCES, 0);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                String uriString = data.toUri(requestCode); 
                editor.putString("Contacts_app", uriString);
                editor.commit();
```

Then i retrieve it like this

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCES, 0);
    String contactsApp = settings.getString("Contacts_app", null);
    try {
        telApp = Intent.parseUri(contactsApp, 0);
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: is it possible to save `(int resultcode,Intent data)` data object in preference?

Comment: Have u got the answer for your question .Please do help me if u did

Answer (score 0):

You could serialize the object to a string, and save the resulting string in the preferences. An easy way would be to serialize it in json format, using [Google Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) for example.

Comment: I'm not familiar with gson, can you provide me an alternative? i looked on how to convert it to uri, than back to intent, but i can't find anything, i found this https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-developers/cffRLznyto0%5B1-25%5D
But it doesn't work, i can save it, but i can't use the getIntent because it says it's deprecated