# How to save onActivityResult Intent data in android?

Tags: android, android-intent, record, onactivityresult, mediaprojectionmanager

i am using **MediaProjectionManager** to record video from app,and also give permission for save audio and media storage.

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />`

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

```
 if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        MediaProjectionManager mediaProjectionManager = (MediaProjectionManager) getSystemService(Context.MEDIA_PROJECTION_SERVICE);
        Intent permissionIntent = mediaProjectionManager != null ? mediaProjectionManager.createScreenCaptureIntent() : null;
        startActivityForResult(permissionIntent, SCREEN_RECORD_REQUEST_CODE);
    }



@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    recorder.startScreenRecording(data, resultCode, this);
 }
```

}

i want to save this Intent data for feature use, means i want to reuse this intent data from after application close and re-open time, i give all runtime permission also. is it possible, then please help.

Thanks.

Comment: That is not possible. Your media projection rights are only good for your current process.

Comment: No, This is possible i saw many other applications which is already on play store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences) to save Variables in Android.

To store

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCES, 0);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                String uriString = data.toUri(requestCode); 
                editor.putString("Contacts_app", uriString);
                editor.commit();
```

To retreive

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCES, 0);
    String contactsApp = settings.getString("Contacts_app", null);
    try {
        telApp = Intent.parseUri(contactsApp, 0);
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

For further information look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11956271/save-intent-in-shared-preference).

Comment: this is not working it will give u exception like com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to android.content.Intent

Comment: Are you sure you did everything like i mentioned it? Because it works in my Application, with my solution.

Comment: is it possible Evan after re-open app after closing application?

Comment: `String uriString = data.toUri(requestCode); ` Try: `String uriString = data.getData().toString();`

Comment: it will not work i check, it will give u nullPointerException.i am using this https://github.com/HBiSoft/HBRecorder library you can check also. i am checking in android 10 device.

Comment: is any solution possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you´ve tried the accepted answer and has not worked let me inform you that from the android documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/parcelables-and-bundles) we learn that

> Note: Parcel is not a general-purpose serialization mechanism, and you should never store any Parcel data on disk or send it over the network.

And taking into account that [Intent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent) implements Parcelable then no wonders why that does not work. I tried with Gson to serialize and then deserialize the intent but did not work, on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68277971/not-getting-exact-intent-object-from-sharedpreferences-after-closing-and-reopeni?noredirect=1#comment120671765_68277971) question I asked on the comments you can also see that

> Beyond the problem that not everything in an Intent can be written
> successfully to disk, your permission to capture
> screenshots/screencasts lives only as long as your process does.
> Writing the Intent to disk will not change that."