# Not getting exact intent object from sharedPreferences after closing and reopening app

Tags: java, android, android-intent, sharedpreferences

I am trying to save to the SharedPreferences the **Intent data** returned from onActivityResult, I´m using Gson to serialize and then deserialize it so I can store it as a string, my code saves and retrieves the data perfectly when I just saved the object and while the application is running, but when I close the app, launch it again and try to get the Intent data object I´m not getting the exact same thing as before, from the debugger I see that the mParcelledData.dataSize is not the same. When the code works the [image] and when it´s not working is [image] other than that everything seems to be the same.

Here is how I get the intent and then store it to the sharedPreferences:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode != REQUEST_CODE && resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
        Toast.makeText(this,
                "Permission Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        mToggleButton.setChecked(false);

    }else if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        Toast.makeText(this,
                "Permission granted, so save the intent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().create();
        String dataS= gson.toJson(data);
        editor.putString(PERMISSION_INTENT, dataS);
        editor.putBoolean(PERMISSION_BOOLEAN,true);
        editor.putInt(PERMISSION_CODE,resultCode);

        editor.commit();
    }

}
```

Here is how I retrieve the intent

```
myButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {


        String intentStored= settings.getString(PERMISSION_INTENT, null);
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().create();
        int mResultCode = settings.getInt(PERMISSION_CODE,0);
        gotPermission = settings.getBoolean(PERMISSION_BOOLEAN,false);
    Intent mData = gson.fromJsonintentStored= Intent.class);



    });
```

and here are my SharedPreferences

```
    private SharedPreferences settings;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_record);

    mToggleButton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggle);
    recordButton = findViewById(R.id.record_btn);
    settings = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(
            getString(R.string.preference_file_key), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Comment: "I am trying to save to the SharedPreferences the Intent data returned from onActivityResult" -- that is not going to work for arbitrary `Intent` extras.

Comment: This is the intent resutling from startActivityForResult(mProjectionManager.createScreenCaptureIntent(), REQUEST_CODE); ---I don´t understand why this works when I just saved the object but then when the app is reopened does not.

Comment: Beyond the problem that not everything in an `Intent` can be written successfully to disk, your permission to capture screenshots/screencasts lives only as long as your process does. Writing the `Intent` to disk will not change that.

Comment: I guess storing the permission will be a security concern, so that´s why we can´t write it to disk. I´m better off now that I know there´s no way to do this, thanks.

Comment: I just read this from the documenation "Note: Parcel is not a general-purpose serialization mechanism, and you should never store any Parcel data on disk or send it over the network." so I think this is also related to the problem.